# How to make a countdown in ruby on rails with flipclock.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, flipclock

I am trying to make a countdown for an offer which ends on July 15, 2016.

I was able to add flipclock to my app but I couldn't figure our how to send the remaining time to the javascript.

Can anyone kindly help?

Here is the code. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Sorry I forgot to mention the timezone.
One offer is at July 15, 2016 GMT
Another offer is at July 25, 2016 EST.

This is my app's timezone on heroku.

```
suai@railrial:~/workspace/conrse (master) $ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0.rc2)
>> Time.zone.name
=> "UTC"
>>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="clock"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(25 * 25 * 35 * 35, {
      clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
      countdown: true,
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm assuming you have **offer end date** as a `DateTime` in your database.

Lets say the value is in `offer_ends` attribute of your `@item` object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // We need to convert the time difference to integer
  time_diff = <%= (@item.offer_ends - Time.now).to_i.abs %>;
  //Rails will put the seconds difference right there, so if you inspect your code will look like this in browser
  //time_diff = 1035937;

  var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(time_diff, {
    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
    countdown: true,
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer. Any idea how I can use timezone with it? I tried this but I am getting wrong countdown time_diff = <%= ((Time.new(2016, 7, 2, 17, 00, 0).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")) - (Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)"))).to_i.abs %>;

Comment: What's the difference are you getting? What you think you should get?

Comment: I am getting UTC - EST instead of EST - EST

Comment: Can you try this? `(Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 17, 00, 0).in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)") - Time.now.in_time_zone("Eastern Time (US & Canada)")).to_i.abs`

Comment: I see what's happening. Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 17, 00, 0) has to be offset with the EST timezone to get correct difference. Any idea how to create the time with the EST time zone? I tried to test it by adding one hour to current time but I get 3 hours difference because Time.utc(2016, 7, 2, 17, 00, 0) creates the time in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I added some code that added the option for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="clock"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date("July 15 2016"); //Create your date object
    var now = new Date(); //Get todays date
    var diff = (date.getTime()/1000) - (now.getTime()/1000); //Calculate differenece
    var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
      clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
      countdown: true,
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the seconds until a date in javascript

```
var targetDate = new Date(2016, 06, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0);//new Date(YYYY, MM, DD, 0, 0, 0, 0);//MM is the month starting from 0;
var now = new Date();
 var dif = (targetDate.getTime() - now.getTime())/1000;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="clock"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flipclock/0.7.8/flipclock.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var targetDate = new Date(2016, 06, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    var now = new Date();
    var dif = (targetDate.getTime() - now.getTime())/1000;
    
    var clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(dif, {
      clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
      countdown: true,
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```